# How to remove html formatting effect in CSS styles

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a simple php-MySql website and presenting the data for the following fields for each entry in the database (through a loop):

1. Title
2. Organisation
3. DetailedInfo

The 'DetailedInfo' field in the database can hold up to 5000 characters. While displaying on the webpage I am only using the first 250 characters.

The problem is as follows. If an entry has a formatting tag (italic/bold) starting, say at character 240, and the formatting tag is not closed by the 250th character then the problem starts. For all subsequent entries the Title, Organisation and DetailedInfo are displayed with the tag (so all the subsequent text are either italic, or, bold). 
I am using CSS style for Title, Organisation and DetailedInfo but it seems that the CSS is not able to get rid of the formatting tag from the data.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Cheers,
Tim

Comment: Great question, by the way. Very clear. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

If you're only displaying a small portion of the `detailedInfo` field I'd guess formatting it isn't that mportant. Use `strip_tags()` to get rid of the formatting tags before you display it.

Comment: Strip_tag() is an option but I would like to keep the formatting - if possible. For me the best option could be: allowing formatted text and then to remove any broken html tag at the end of each iteration. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You'd have to scan for any tags, work out whether they're closed within the block, and recreate any unclosed tags in the correct order, whilst shortening the text you're displayin to allow for them, which could break further formatting... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but still did not understand. How can I automatically scan for the presence of any unclosed tags and if it is there how do I close it?

Comment: If you're asking that question I'd suggest that it's not possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot fix broken HTML. You'll need to strip it back to plain text and re-code (or just leave it out).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t fix that with CSS (and I don’t think it’s possible). You’re outputting invalid HTML, which is going to cause problems, especially if anyone ever looks a the page in IE 8 or earlier.

It could also be worse than an unclosed tag. What if the excerpt ends with `</i`?

I’d either implement some crazy logic to close any unclosed HTML tags in the 250-character excerpt, or strip all HTML tags from the excerpt. I’m guessing the latter would be easier.